# JavaFX redirect to web page

Tags: html, redirect, javafx

Does anyone know a simple way to get, for example, a button action event within a web deployed java fx application to direct the browser to a new web page?

So in my application I want to go to the home page of my website when the user clicks a javafx button.

I think this can be done with javascript & javafx, but i think it is messy......

Answer (score 2):

```
application.getHostServices().showDocument("http://www.mywebsite.org");
```

[hostServices.showDocument(uri)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument%28java.lang.String%29)

> Opens the specified URI in a new browser window or tab. The
>   determination of whether it is a new browser window or a tab in an
>   existing browser window will be made by the browser preferences. Note
>   that this will respect the pop-up blocker settings of the default
>   browser; it will not try to circumvent them.